# Отправка только выбранных инпутов через AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form, phpmailer

Для отправки формы на почту использую такой код:

```
//E-mail Ajax Send
   $("#order-form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

В форме есть 35 инпутов с одинаковым атрибутом "name" и все скрыты классом .visuallyHidden. Есть список продуктов и при клике, инпут с таким же атрибутом "value" становится видимым в форме. И мне нужно отправить через форму только те инпуты, у которых нет класса .visuallyHidden.

```
   <input class="product__cheese hidden" type="text" value="Beef" name="product" readonly>
   <input class="product__potato hidden" type="text" value="potato" name="product" readonly>
   <input class="product__chicken hidden" type="text" value="chicken" name="product" readonly>
   <input class="product__milk hidden" type="text" value="milk" name="product" readonly> .........
```

Но так не получается, вместо этого, неважно имеет класс .visuallyHidden или нет, всегда отправляется первый инпут из формы в DOM.

Как можно выбрать инпуты только без класса .hidden, через Ajax передать в mail.php и отправить на почту?

Comment: эээ 35 спрятанных инпутов с одним и тем же именем... Зачем?

Comment: Пытался добиться такого результата через append() при клике. Но там другие проблемы. Поэтому решил попробовать таким способом.

Comment: Дело в том, что name для того и нужен, чтобы на сервере в $_POST['name'] получить значение того или иного инпута. Если у Вас 35 одинаковых неймов, естественно на сервер придёт только один - и не важно, скрытые они или открытые. Вы лучше напишите, какая задача изначально перед Вами стоит (потому что путь, по которому Вы пытаетесь идти, заведомо неверный).

Comment: Задача отправить заказ на почту. Я не умею делать корзину, поэтому пошёл таким путём)) Есть список продуктов. Когда посетитель кликает на "заказать" у определённого продукта, он появляется в форме заказа. После чего отправить выбранный список на почту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика может быть примерно такой:

```js
 $('.product').click(function(){ // при клике на заказ продукта
  var value = $(this).attr('data-value'); // получаем значение его data-value
  $('[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){ // в цикле проходим по всем инпутам
   if($(this).attr('name') == value) { // сравниваем их имена с data-value
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden'); // открываем/скрываем сам инпут
    $(this).next('span').toggleClass('hidden'); // ...и описание
    $(this).prop('checked', function(idx, oldProp) { // убираем/снимаем галочку
              return !oldProp;
          });
   }
  });
 });

 $("#order-form").submit(function() {
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php",
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function(data) { //получаем ответ от сервера
            alert(data); //выводим этот ответ
            setTimeout(function() { //возвращаем форму в исходное состояние
             $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
                $('[type="checkbox"]').addClass('hidden');
                $('[type="checkbox"]').next('span').addClass('hidden');
            }, 500);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

```css
.product {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 15px;
 text-align: center;
}
form {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 15px;
   border-radius: 15px;
   margin-top: 30px;
  }
.hidden {
   display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="product" data-value="beef">
 <p>BEEF</p>
 <button>order</button>
</div>

<div class="product" data-value="potato">
 <p>POTATO</p>
 <button>order</button>
</div>

<div class="product" data-value="chicken">
 <p>CHICKEN</p>
 <button>order</button>
</div>

<div class="product" data-value="milk">
 <p>MILK</p>
 <button>order</button>
</div>

<form id="order-form" method="POST" action="mail.php">
 <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="beef" value="beef"> <span class="hidden">BEEF </span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="potato" value="potato"> <span class="hidden">POTATO </span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="chicken" value="chicken"> <span class="hidden">CHICKEN </span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="milk" value="milk"> <span class="hidden">MILK</span> <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

А в mail.php обрабатываем данные следующим образом:

```
foreach($_POST as $value) { // пробегаем в цикле по массиву $_POST
    $result .= $value.' '; // формируем строку из полученных значений
}
if($result != '') { // если строка не пустая
    $message = 'Your order includes: '.$result; // формируем сообщение
    mail('mail@mail.ru', 'Your order', $message); // отправляем его по почте
    echo $message; // возвращаем его в ajax (будет выведено alert'ом)
}
else { // если отправлена пустая форма, выводим сообщение с просьбой сделать заказ
    echo 'Please, make your order!';
}
```